# Getting a column from .sqlite containing multiple tables with multiple columns

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, android-cursor, sqlitemanager

![Database consists of multiple tables and multiple columns as shown & i have pasted this law.sqlite in assets folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74ge3.png)

Database consists of multiple tables and multiple columns as shown & i have pasted this law.sqlite in assets folder.

Suppose i want to access all the elements of column **AS_name** as shown . So how should i code for it?

Comment: Column AS_NAME is in multiple tables?

Comment: What is the full name of the database file ? Mention it this way: "filename.extension"

Comment: @shree202 **law.sqlite**

Comment: Think you should create `.db` file instead of `.sqlite`

Comment: Any suggested tutorial or links for that?

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5949629/1739882

Comment: @shree202 Android supports .sqlite extension. Check here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/oNsnkK7jQmA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and now the problem is solved :

For anyone facing similar type of problem can try my implementation :

**Step 1:**

Make a GetterSetter class (named `GS` here) & generate the [Getter-Setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters) of variables used.

Like in my case:

```
public class GS {
     String AS_name;

public String getAS_name() {
return AS_name;
}

public void setAS_name(String aS_name) {
AS_name = aS_name;
}
}
```

**Step 2:**

Make a `DBAdapter` class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` & in that assign the your name of the file with extension .sqlite !

Rest you need only to copy my `DBAdapter.java` code & take care to implement the method `getData()` in which the data from database is fetched !

```
public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
CustomAdapter adapter;
static String name = "law.sqlite"; //--Replace it with ur sqlite name 
static String path = "";
static ArrayList<GS> gs;
static SQLiteDatabase sdb;

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
} 

private DBAdapter(Context v) 
{
    super(v, name, null, 1);
    path = "/data/data/" + v.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/databases";
}

public boolean checkDatabase()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try 
    {
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path + "/" + name, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (db == null) 
    {
        return false;
    } 
    else
    {
        db.close();
        return true;
    }
}

public static synchronized DBAdapter getDBAdapter(Context v)
{
    return (new DBAdapter(v));
}

public void createDatabase(Context v) 
{
    this.getReadableDatabase();
    try
    {
        InputStream myInput = v.getAssets().open(name);
        // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = path +"/"+ name;
        // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) 
    {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
        // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void openDatabase() 
{
    try 
    {
        sdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path + "/" + name, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public ArrayList<GS> getData() 
{
    try{
    Cursor c1 = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Articles", null);
    gs = new ArrayList<GS>();
    while (c1.moveToNext())
    {
        GS q1 = new GS();

        q1.setAS_name(c1.getString(3)); //--- here 3 represents column no.
        Log.v("AS_name",q1.AS_name+""); 
        gs.add(q1);

    }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return gs;
}
}
```

**Step 3:**

The class `MainActivity.java` :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<GS> q = new ArrayList<GS>();
CustomAdapter adapter;
ListView lv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       // Get ListView object from xml
     lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    DBAdapter db = DBAdapter.getDBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    if (!db.checkDatabase()) 
    {
        db.createDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    }
    db.openDatabase();

    q = db.getData();
    for(int i=0;i<q.size();i++)
    {
        Log.i("outside",""+q.get(i).getAS_name());
    }
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,q));
    //lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}

class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GS>
  {
       ArrayList<GS> list;
       LayoutInflater mInfalter;    
       public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GS> list)
       {
           super(context,R.layout.customlayout,list);
          this.list= list;  
          mInfalter = LayoutInflater.from(context);
          for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
         {
             Log.i("................",""+list.get(i).getAS_name());
         }

       }
//         public int getCount(){
//              return list.size();
//          }
       @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          ViewHolder holder;
          Log.i("..........","Hello in getView");
          if(convertView==null)
          {
               convertView = mInfalter.inflate(R.layout.customlayout,parent,false);//--customlayout.xml must have a textView 
               holder = new ViewHolder();
               holder.tv1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
               convertView.setTag(holder); 
          }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
          } 

                holder.tv1.setText(list.get(position).getAS_name());
          return convertView;
    }

  }
 static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView tv1;
    }  
}
```

Run this code & finally the list in the listview will be displayed !  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT AS_name FROM Articles",null);
// If you want in order then  add "ORDER BY AS_name AESC" in sql query.

cursor.moveToFirst();

 while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
// do Something
}
```

Comment: Make sure to copy this database from asset folder to database folder.

Comment: Check this link to copy a database from asset to app database folder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941404/how-to-access-and-query-the-database-that-is-copied-to-the-assets-folder

Comment: I figure out the problem ! [View my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21460871/2715065) & +1 for the query ! Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c = db.query(
                            TABLE_NAME,  // The table to query
                            projection,                               // The columns to return
                            null,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
                            null,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
                            null,                                     // don't group the rows
                            null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
                            sortOrder                                 // The sort order
                            );
```

Specify the table name in TABLE_NAME field. Then access the elements using

```
c.moveToFirst();
for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
{
 //access elements of column here
 long itemId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Column_Name)); //Example with long, corresponding function for string etc also exists.
 c.moveToNext();
}

c.close();
```

Specify the column name in Column_name.

**NOTE:**  If this column is in **multiple** tables, just put both these code snippets in a loop and iterate through it. May be you can store the table names in an arraylist and access each table in each iteration of the *outermost* loop. Hope this helps you!!!