# No such a column: R1.ReadingDate Error

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a view in sqlite using sqlite manager.

```
Create View vMeterReading
as
SELECT M._id as Meter_id, M.MeterNumber, R1.ReadingDate, R1.Reading AS              CurrentReading, R2.ReadingDate AS PrevReadingDate, R2.Reading AS PrevMeterReading, R2.Rate  as Rate, R2._id,R1.TenantMeter_id
FROM (Meters AS M INNER JOIN TenantMeters ON M._id = TenantMeters.Meter_id) INNER JOIN (MeterReading AS R1 INNER JOIN MeterReading AS R2 ON R1.TenantMeter_id = R2.TenantMeter_id) ON TenantMeters._id = R1.TenantMeter_id
WHERE (((R2.ReadingDate)=(SELECT Max(R3.ReadingDate) 
      FROM [MeterReading] AS R3   
      WHERE (R3.TenantMeter_id = R1.TenantMeter_id)   
        AND (R3.ReadingDate < R1.ReadingDate)     
    ))) OR (((R2.TenantMeter_id) Is Null))
ORDER BY M.MeterNumber, R1.ReadingDate.
```

I have tried to use this view (`select * from vMeterReading`) in android and I get the error as titled.

I have also connected to the sqlite db from command prompt and tried to execute the same query. I get the same error.

What is wrong with the sql statement?

It works well in sql manager(firefox add-on).

Comment: Please paste your create statement. Is your database created in data/data/<APPNAME>/database/ folder.Check thru sqlite browser. If yes, then delete from data/data/<APPNAME>/database/ and restart the app. Please comment, if you have any problem.

Comment: Hello Zohra. I am using a pre-created database.

Comment: then you must copy your database from asset folder to application database folder.

Comment: Check this link to copy database from asset to database folder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941404/how-to-access-and-query-the-database-that-is-copied-to-the-assets-folder

Comment: Hello Zohra. I am using a pre-created database.The database is created and i can see it in databases folder you have mentioned.i can even connect to it from command prompt. Even a connection at the command prompt results into the same error if i excute the sql to select data from the view.Tables:Meters _ID,MeterNumber, MeterReading -id,TenantMeter_id, ReadingDate,Reading. TenantMeter table _id, Meter_id, Tenant_id. Table Tenants _id, FirstName.

Comment: Have you copied it to database folder?

Comment: Yes i did and it is created because i can see it in the folder data/data/com.example.metermanager/databases/meter_app.sqlite. I can even connect via command prompt to the created db when emulator running.

Comment: Delete your database from database folder and restart your app. One more thing Can you see android_metadata file in sqlite browser?

Comment: I have it with a field locale with a value en_US

Comment: Sorry, no  idea then. You can ask laalto. He is expert.

Comment: Your query is really terminated by a period (`.`)? If so, use a semi-colon (`;`).

Comment: Hello. This how i construct the query.String selectQuery = " SELECT "  + KEY_ID +"," + TENANT+ "," + READINGDATEVIEW + "," + CurrentREADING + ","+ PrevREADINGDATE +","+ prevREADING +","+ UNITs+","+ RATE + ","+ AMOUNT + " FROM "+ VIEW_DETAILEDREADING;

Comment: This time i have managed to return data from the database and printed it in the logcat! I am making progress i believe though the query for the view still cause the error i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite makes no guarantees whether a table name prefix (like `R1.1`) is part of the result column name, or not.

You should explicitly give a name to all the view's columns with `AS`.

Comment: Made the changes as advised but still no luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the SQLite version used by android is not the same as the version used by sQLite manager. The android version does not support the join i was using.
The query below executes with out problems.
Got this advice from this site http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/

```
SELECT M._id as Meter_id, M.MeterNumber, R1.ReadingDate as ReadingDate,
R1.Reading AS CurrentReading, R2.ReadingDate AS PrevReadingDate, R2.Reading
AS PrevMeterReading, R2.Rate as Rate, R2._id as _id,R1.TenantMeter_id as TenantMeterID
FROM Meters AS M INNER JOIN TenantMeters ON M._id = TenantMeters.Meter_id
INNER JOIN MeterReading AS R1 ON R1.TenantMeter_id = TenantMeters ._id
 INNER JOIN MeterReading AS R2 ON
R1.TenantMeter_id = R2.TenantMeter_id 

WHERE (((R2.ReadingDate)=(SELECT Max(R3.ReadingDate)
      FROM [MeterReading] AS R3
      WHERE (R3.TenantMeter_id = R1.TenantMeter_id)
        AND (R3.ReadingDate < R1.ReadingDate)
    ))) OR (((R2.TenantMeter_id) Is Null))
```